Is there a hook for 'before_feature' in pytest-bdd?
The requirement is to run a code once for all scenarios in the feature file based on a custom tag defined at the feature level. I have defined my custom tags in pytest.ini.
However, the following code executes for every scenario in the feature file. I need it to execute only once regardless of how many scenarios reside in the feature file:
@pytest.hookimpl()
@pytest.mark.tag_is_at_feature_level
def pytest_bdd_before_scenario(request, feature, scenario):
    if "tag_is_at_feature_level" in feature.tags:
        print(f"This process should run only once regardless of how many scenarios in the feature file...")

Here is the feature file:
@tag_is_at_feature_level
Feature: TableStructureValidation
     This feature is to validate table structure

        Scenario: Table Structure Validation - table_name
             When I query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for the table "table_name" from the databse "database_name"
             Then I should see following table definition in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS:
                  | COLUMN_NAME         | COLUMN_DEFAULT | IS_NULLABLE | DATA_TYPE | 
                  | FileName            |                | YES         | varchar   | 
                  | TotalRowsSourceFile |                | YES         | bigint    | 
                  | TotalRowsLoadedToDB |                | YES         | bigint    | 
                  | Validation          |                | YES         | varchar   | 
                  | LoadTime            | (getdate())    | YES         | datetime  | 


I think you can try this to see if it works, I remember working with something like this before:

You can define a session-scoped fixture to manage state across your tests. This fixture will check if a specific tag is present at the feature level and execute the code only once per feature.
Use this fixture in your scenarios so that the initial setup runs only once when the feature starts, regardless of the number of scenarios.



import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers

# Define a fixture that checks for the custom tag and runs once per feature
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def check_feature_tag(request):
    feature_tags = request.node.iter_markers_with_node(name='tag_is_at_feature_level')
    has_tag = any(node for marker, node in feature_tags if node.parent is None)  # Check if the tag is at the feature level
    if has_tag:
        print("This process should run only once regardless of how many scenarios in the feature file.")

# Use the fixture in your scenarios
@scenario('your_feature_file.feature', 'Table Structure Validation - table_name')
def test_table_structure():
    pass

@given("I query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for the table 'table_name' from the database 'database_name'")
def step_impl():
    # Your step implementation here
    pass

@then("I should see following table definition in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS:")
def step_impl():
    # Your step implementation here
    pass

# Make sure to use the fixture in the test function
def test_features(check_feature_tag):
    # This test function will use the fixture that runs once per feature
    pass



